# Magento 2 Override Abstract class

Tags: overrides

I need to override Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod class. because I need to customize getTitle method of this class.

I searched in Google all are saying to use plugin but how I could?

Can anyone let me know how we can override abstract class method?